# httpvueloader all children mounted

Tags: vuejs2

I have a parent component which loads other child components via httpvueloader. The problem I am facing now is that it seems that with httpvueloader the normal order of lifecycle hooks is not valid anymore. When logging the created and mounted events in both my parent and my child component I can see that first the parent component is created and mounted and THEN the child component is created and mounted. I am guessing this is due to httpvueloader and I think I can work around that. However, to do that I would need a way of knowing when all child components are mounted. I have tried to achive this using events like this:
in parent:

```
created: function(){
    this.$on('childMounted', function(){
        console.log("child mounted"); 
    })
},
```

and in child:

```
mounted: function() {
    this.$emit('childMounted');
}.
```

However this doesnt seem to work either, because the parent never receives the 'childMounted' event. What I am missing here?

UPDATE: after just a little more research I figured it out. First off, `this.$on()` only works for events from the same component, so this was wrong. However, what I have to do is listen to the event by registering the listener on the template like this `<childComponent @child-mounted="foo()"></childComponent>` (renamed the event because HTML attributes are case-insensitive and you cant use v-on to listen to camelCase events when using in-DOM templates).
What helped me was this [thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue2-0-parent-component-cannot-listen-to-emit-event-in-child-component-by-on/2336) and more specifically this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dangvanthanh/3m6s54qx/).

Comment: does this code `this.$on('childMounted', function(){
        console.log("child mounted"); 
    })` work?